# How to change ALL the postfixes of files in a single directory, single command

Tags: rename, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean up file extensions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/how-to-clean-up-file-extensions)

have a directory full of files ending with .JPG I need to change them all to .jpg
How?

Comment: This has been asked many times already.  Please use search before posting duplicate questions.