# Changing file extensions

Tags: bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming multiple files (changing extension)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/renaming-multiple-files-changing-extension)

Suppose I have a bunch of files with the extension `.x` and I want to change them so that they have the extension `.y`. I know `$ mv *.x *.y` wouldn't work because I havn't expressed each file to change their respective extensions (that and the command expects *.y to be a directory).

What command should I issue?

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19654/renaming-multiple-files-changing-extension & http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/how-to-clean-up-file-extensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rename` to rename files based on a pattern, and one of the examples from the `man` page is changing the extension of a group of files. It takes the source pattern, modified pattern, and the files to operate on, so in your case:

```
$ rename .x .y *.x
```

It changes the first occurrence of `.x` to `.y`, so if you happen to have `.x` anywhere other than the end of the filename it's going to change that first

Comment: I get this:

$ rename .x .y *.x
Transliteration pattern not terminated at (eval 1) line 2.

However 's/.x/.y/' as a pattern seems to work.

Comment: You have to take into account the difference between Red Hat `rename` and Debian `rename`. And then there are Unices that have neither.

Comment: That's annoyingly distro-specific...