# File extension case sensitivity on CentOS

Tags: centos, rename, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean up file extensions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6777/how-to-clean-up-file-extensions)

I'm using CentOS. There are >10M images in one of my folders, which are furthur grouped into subdirectories.

The issue is that some of my images are named as abc.**jpg** and others are named as xyz.**JPG**. So, when i try to access xyz.jpg, it says "File not found" as the extension is case-sensitive.

Is there any way to rename all `JPG` to `jpg`, or a httpd config which works around this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (this will rename all .JPG files to .jpg recursively, in all the subdirectories of the directory where you run this):

```
find . -name '*.JPG' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.JPG}.jpg"' {} \;
```

The find searches for all files named *.JPG in the current directory and its subdirectories, passes the list to the mv command which renames them

Comment: more answers [here](http://superuser.com/questions/213134/recursively-rename-files-change-extension-in-linux)

Answer (score 3):

As always with this kind of questions and answers, a few words of caution:

```
find . -name '*.JPG' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.JPG}.jpg"' {} \;
```

While it will work OK for most people in most cases, it's dangerous to advertise it publicly as it got a few issues that may turn to security issues in some contexts.

That renames both files and directories. If renaming directories, it will fail to rename files within (use the -depth option)

It will potentially lose files (foo.JPG renamed to foo.jpg while there already was a foo.jpg), or potentially put files where you don't want to (consider for instance a directory where there's a file called foo.JPG and one called foo.jpg that is actually a symlink to /etc/apache2/conf.d. It will potentially break symlinks. There's a race condition that can allow an attacker trick you into renaming any file.

Many of those issues can be avoided by using a tool dedicated for that task (batch renaming of files) instead of trying to reinvent the  wheel. mmv and zsh's zmv come to mind.